# How to spy stopPropagation with Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

basically, I have a link that stops propagation when clicked.

**html**

```
<a href="#" id="myLink">My Link</a>
```

**JavaScript**

```
const a = document.querySelector('#myLink');

a.addEventListener('click', (e) => { e.stopPropagation(); });
```

I want to test if my link will really stop the propagation. However, my unit test is failing...

**Jasmine**

```
it('ensure that iframe\'s html links doesn\'t trigger actions', () => {
  spyOn(window.event, 'stopPropagation');

  const a = document.querySelector('#myLink');
  a.dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));
  expect(window.event.stopPropagation).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please, let me know if you have a more elegant answer. After some tries, I figured out how to solve this problem.

**Jasmine**

```
it('ensure that iframe\'s html links doesn\'t trigger actions', () => 
{
  const ev = new Event('click');
  spyOn(ev, 'stopPropagation');

  const a = document.querySelector('#myLink');
  a.dispatchEvent(ev);
  expect(ev.stopPropagation).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```